# Do closed system always have real boundary?

Tags: thermodynamics

Let's consider a system in uniform air with imaginary boundary. As air flow inside and outside of the imaginary boundary, mass is exchanging. But within that system, mass is necessarily fixed.

Can I consider this as closed system??

Comment: How is mass fixed if mass is also exchanging?  Do you mean the exchange rate is constant for inwards and outwards mass transfer?

Comment: Yup, exchange rate is constant.

Comment: So, can I assume that closed system always have real boundary?

Comment: @user185991 I have modified my answer slightly for your further consideration. I removed (not physical) following the word imaginary in the last paragraph. It occurred to me that a boundary can be real without being physical (material in nature). Although the Earth's gravity (my comment on Sagar Ghosh) is not strong enough to prevent molecules to escape, a black hole's is. Don't know much about black holes, but it's my understanding a black hole is a closed system and its boundary is the event horizon. The boundary is not material in nature, but nonetheless real.

Comment: But in my sense, gravitational pull of black holes are strong enough to pull anything around it. Though I also don't know much about black holes. It will be pulling other celestial bodies into it. So in that case mass will cross it's real(not physical) boundary. In this way black holes also will be open system. Isn't it??                           PS: I may be wrong. It's just a piece of my thought. Please point out my mistake, if there are any!!

Answer (score 1):

The system you describe is still not a closed system, and should not be treated as such in thermodynamics analyses. This is an open system, operating at "steady state." For how to handle such a system in thermodynamic calculations, research open system (control volume) version of first law of thermodynamics.  It is treated in every thermodynamics textbook.

Answer (score 0):

No this can't be considered as a closed system. A closed is defined as a system which does not exchanges any mass with the surrounding. Changes in temperature, pressure, volume can be done by the surroundings as well as internally.

On the other hand, an isolated system can't exchange any mass or any energy with the surroundings. There should not be any change in temperature, pressure and volume due to surroundings, although these might change due to internal effects.

Comment: In engineering, we regard the system you describe as isolated, rather than closed.  In engineering, a closed system is one for which no mass transfer is allowed, but for which heat transfer is allowed.

Comment: you are right, closed systems can exchange energy but isolated systems can't

Answer (score -2):

I think it's not necessary as well. Consider the earth as a system and the rest of the Universe as a surroundings. Now Due to the atmospheric pressure and earth's own gravity field, the air and the water ( in gaseous state) can not be exhausted to the outer space. Thus earth can be considered as a closed system. Somebody may make a mistake thinking that it's an isolated system but the point is that sunrays falling on it raises the temperature and thus energy interaction with the surrounding occurs. But there is no real boundary even it's a closed system. * A boundary is the imaginary surface that separets the portion of universe on which our concentration is encountered. It's always hypothetical. So far, thermodynamics is developed, no real boundary is known.
    Suppose consider a cylinder piston arrangements in which some amount of thermodynamic fluid is confined. If you consider the fluid as a system, then will you consider the cylinder and piston as the boundary? The answer is simply no. Because the boundary is the imaginary surface the separates the fluid from the rest of the Universe that is the cylinder piston and the surrounding as well. Hope that may clarify your confusion.*

Comment: What about a falling meteorite not destroyed by atmospheric drag! It contains definite amount of mass and it's crossing the boundary. So isn't earth a open system?

Comment: @Sagar Ghosh. It is not true that air and water in the gaseous state can not be exhausted to the outer space. Consider the following statement. " Even with the gravitational field, in the upper thin part of the atmosphere, a molecule moving outwards has little chance of colliding with another and would therefore be able to escape if it has sufficient speed". Luca Montabone, Atmospheric, Oceanic and Planetary Physics dept., Oxford University). The rate is slow and the earth is safe for a long time. But it is an open system.

Comment: Here's the link https://www.thenakedscientists.com/articles/questions/earth-losing-water-space